# Cant generate my APK signed with proguard enable

Tags: android, proguard

I can't generate my signed apk show me this warnings with Facebook and configuration Facebook in `proguard-rules.pro` doesn't help

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before ';' in line 37 of file '/Users/ederpadilla/Downloads/driveappuble-drive-android-484‌​430cd00e7/app/progua‌​rd-rules.pro' 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. > Job failed, see logs for details
```

line 37, I've got :

```
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.** { ; }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you scroll down message log?

Comment: Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting java type before ';' in line 37 of file '/Users/ederpadilla/Downloads/driveappuble-drive-android-484430cd00e7/app/proguard-rules.pro'

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

Comment: Padila check line 37 of your proguard-rules.pro. The error told that it need ";"

Comment: -keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.** { ; }

Comment: it already have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests your are missing the type to keep, To keep class names under `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` package (mind the `*`) :

```
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.** { *; }
```